# What classes in VB has default initialization?

Tags: vb.net

I am not even sure that default initialization is the correct word.

For example, I know that a string defaults to "". If we declare a string and we don't initialize it, it's "".

We also know that most numbers, long, integer, single, double, defaults to 0 or false.

So `dim a= list (of boolean)(100)` will give a list of 100 boolean whose values are false.

Are there samples? Are variables in vb.net always preinitialize?

Bonus: What about in other languages? What languages have this feature and what's not?

Comment: Hmm, no, a string that's not initialized defaults to Nothing.  Like any reference type.  The runtime guarantees that the storage of a variable is initialized with binary zeros.  Depending on the variable type, that represents Nothing, 0, False, Keys.None, etc.

Comment: any link for that?

Comment: `Dim a = New List(Of Boolean)(100)` doesn't *give a list of 100 boolean whose values are false*. This pre-defines a Capacity, but you have no items there. Try `Console.WriteLine(a(10))` to get an exception that explains what's wrong.

Comment: On strings defaulting to Nothing, a confusing point can be whether the vb runtime or framework methods are used on that string variable.  See [Nothing and Strings in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/nothing-and-strings). For example, with `Dim s As String`, `Debug.Print(IsNothing(s).ToString)` prints "True", `Debug.Print(Len(s).ToString)` prints "0", while `Debug.Print(s.Length.ToString)` will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: So all objects got initialized to nothing and all value type goes to 0?